# trying to create multiple instances of a struct using array at the end but the code doesn't save anything at all

Tags: arrays, c

There isn't a single webpage that explains how I can use make struct like this and can only find an example in my book. So I'm trying it out and it wont save or print anything at all.

```
//array struct?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct testing
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[5];
} t[3];

void main()
{
    struct testing;
    t[1].a = 10;
    t[1].b = 20;
    strcpy("thing", t[1].c);

    printf("%d %d %s", t[1].a, t[1].b, t[1].c);
}
```

as you can see, `t[1].a` is suppose to store 10. That `printf` doesn't print a single thing. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Look up the order of arguments to `strcpy`. The destination comes first. Also, a string literal `"thing"` has size `6` not `5`.

Comment: Try running your program in a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: On an unrelated thing, what do you think the statement `struct testing;` does?

Comment: OT: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: @Cheatah I don't understand, how does messing up the data size for ```c``` variable mess up everything else?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I assume it calls the struct data type

Comment: The problem here is not the size. The problem is that you are using a string literal (i.e. "thing") as destination for `strcpy`. That is illegal. Further, since you never assign to `t[1].c` it isn't safe to print it. The size will however be a problem once you fix the code to be `strcpy(t[1].c, "thing");` .... then there is too little memory to hold a copy of "thing". Remeber that C strings require an extra char to hold the string termination charaqcter

Comment: There's no such thing as "calling" a structure type. It's equivalent to a forward declaration of the structure name, but since it's already been declared (and defined) above there's no use of it.

Comment: @imgesus Maybe you don't understand because you focus only on the second half of my comment. Let's focus on the *first* half first. Did you look up the order of arguments to `strcpy`? Do you understand what we mean by that?

Comment: @lmgesus `strcpy("thing", t[1].c);` -> `strcpy(t[1].c, "thing");`. But this isn't gong to end well either, `"thing"` needs 6 bytes, not 5, you need to take the null terminator into account.

Comment: @lmgesus _"how does messing up the data size for c variable mess up everything else"_: you have a buffer overflow here, this will lead to _undefined bahaviour_ which includes "messing up evreything else".

Comment: @Jabberwocky how does buffer overflow at a later line affect codes that are above. or is this something I have to study cs for because i thought codes that are written physically above are executed first, hence a and b gets assigned 10 and 20 respectively first.

Comment: @lmgesus google "undefined behaviour C". During a buffer overflow you write beyond the memory allocated to your buffer/array. This memory  might be unused, it might belong to another variable of your program, it might be a system variable etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, with fixes applied and commented:

```
//array struct?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct testing
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[6]; /* increased space to fit "thing" with terminator */
} t[3];

int main(void) /* changed return type to int, and args to void */
{
    t[0].a = 10; /* the first instance is at 0, C indexes from zero */
    t[0].b = 20;
    strcpy(t[0].c, "thing"); /* corrected argument order, and index 0 */

    printf("%d %d %s", t[0].a, t[0].b, t[0].c); /* use index 0 */
    return 0; /* added missing return */
}
```

Comment: I dont understand why people are telling me to use ```int main(void)``` instead of ```void main()``` what am I missing out on by not using the former?

Comment: The language standard says that `main()` returns `int`. It's possible for implementations to support/allow other return types, but I don't see the point in using non-standard code in answers to programming questions, that just adds more confusion.